# Configuration for recording file in Android that can be used for Google Speech To Text API?

Tags: android, audio-recording, google-cloud-speech

I want to record an audio file from Android phone then want to use this audio file for Google Speech To Text API. I have successfully tested mp3 file that I converted from website but when I try to use my own recording file then Google always gives error `"Bad Encoding"`. I have tried a lot of configurations but still not able to succeed.

Here is code for creating mp3 file in Android:

```java
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
```

Here is the code for sending audio file to Google API:

```java
     try {
            mApi.recognize(
                    RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED)
                                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                                    .setSampleRateHertz(48000)
                                    .build())
                            .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                                    .setContent(ByteString.readFrom(stream))
                                    .build())
                            .build(),
                    mFileResponseObserver);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading the input", e);
        }
```

Above code works well for mp3 file that is created using online website.

Comment: What's the encoding and format of your recordings? Your recording probably have a different encoding than what you have declared in the config --> https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/error-messages#invalid_recognition_config_bad_encoding

Comment: I have mentioned my encoding on first part of my question. And in Google Docs I don't find any helpful material.

Comment: you specified your encoding as ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED where it's expecting a different encoding. Try to play with different encodings like MP3, etc.

Comment: Yes that works fine on Mp3 file. But problem is Android Code. Which is not compatible with below confgurations.